# JavaFX Dragboard.hasString() returns true but getString() returns null

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

When using the following on drag dropped method, the `hasString` method returns true, but `getString` sometimes returns null. It has worked, but is inconsistent

This has been tested with a URL such as http://localhost:8080/browse/DPM-2 as well as dragging the same text from a text file

This is running on Ubuntu 18, using Java 11 with the openjfx javafx dependencies in Maven.

```
this.table.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
    if (e.getDragboard().hasString())
    {
        try
        {
            final URL url = new URL(e.getDragboard().getString());
            this.repositoryController.getRepository(url)
                        .ifPresent(r -> populateTable());
            e.setDropCompleted(true);
        }
        catch (final MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }
    e.consume();
});
```

Table is a TreeTableView, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: I assume you tested it using native drag (from outside the javafx application). Is this same inconsistency present if you populate the dragBoard yourself (e.i. From another javafx component)? And have you been able to test it de on another device/platform? If so, what are the results?

Comment: Native drag is consistent, haven't got around to trying from another component yet as I would have to create something for that purpose. From what I can tell windows doesn't have the same issue, but my win 10 machine doesn't have my dev env so I haven't thoroughly tested it yet